# sort array of multiple inheritance objects by date

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I'm having an array `array: [AnyObject]` which contain a number of different inheritance objects for instance `Dog` or `Cat`. I would like to sort these by date how can i do this?

The classes could for instance look like this

```
class Pet {
    var: NSDate = NSDate()
}

class Dog: Pet {
}

class Cat: Pet {
}
```

So far i've created this class, which is suppose to handle the sorting and return a new array with the objects sorted

```
class FavoriteSorter {
    func sortOrganizationsByDistanceFromLocation(orgArray:[AnyObject]) -> [AnyObject] {


        let sortedArray = orgArray.sort {

        }



        return sortedArray

    }
}
```

Comment: Can the array only contain subclasses of `Pet`?

Comment: your right it can ONLY contain subclasses of Pet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
class Pet {
    var myDate = NSDate()
    var title = String()
}

class Dog: Pet {
}

class Cat: Pet {
}


var dog1 = Dog()
dog1.myDate = NSDate()
dog1.title = "Dog 1"

var dog2 = Dog()
dog2.myDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:NSTimeInterval(10))
dog2.title = "Dog 2"

var cat1 = Cat()
cat1.myDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:NSTimeInterval(20))
cat1.title = "Cat 1"

var cat2 = Cat()
cat2.myDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:NSTimeInterval(15))
cat2.title = "Cat 2"

var arrayOfObjs = [cat1, cat2, dog1, dog2]

// Sorting array
func sortOrganizationsByDistanceFromLocation(array:[AnyObject]) -> [AnyObject] {
    return array.sort{ ($0.0 as! Pet).myDate.compare(($0.1 as! Pet).myDate) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
}

let sortedArray = sortOrganizationsByDistanceFromLocation(arrayOfObjs) as! [Pet]

print(sortedArray[0].title); // Prints Dog 1
print(sortedArray[1].title); // Prints Dog 2
print(sortedArray[2].title); // Prints Cat 2
print(sortedArray[3].title); // Prints Cat 1
```

Comment: When you make it as! [Pet] will i then be able to access particular attributes from Dog and Cat class?

Comment: So for instance i could just change to `func sortContentByDate(array:[Pet]) -> [Pet] {`

Comment: Yes, then you do not need this type casting.

Comment: This is a copy paste from my answer. You didn't even changed the parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

```
class FavoriteSorter {
    func sortOrganizationsByDistanceFromLocation(array:[AnyObject]) -> [AnyObject] {
        return array.sort{ ($0.0 as! Pet).date.compare(($0.1 as! Pet).date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
    }
}
```

As mentioned by vacawama it would be better to pass [Pet] instead of [AnyObject] to avoid crashing your app in case you pass another object type:

```
class FavoriteSorter {
    func sortOrganizationsByDistanceFromLocation(array:[Pet]) -> [Pet] {
        return array.sort{ $0.date.compare($1.date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending }
    }
}

class Pet {
    var date = NSDate()
}
class Dog: Pet { }
class Cat: Pet { }

let dog = Dog()
let cat = Cat()

let date01 = NSDate()
let date02 = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(3600)

dog.date = date01
cat.date = date02

let pets = [dog,cat]
pets.description   // "[Dog, Cat]"

let sortedPets = FavoriteSorter().sortOrganizationsByDistanceFromLocation(pets)
sortedPets.description   //  "[Cat, Dog]"
```

Comment: Just some tidying suggestions:  Wouldn't `$0` and `$1`  work as well instead of `$0.0` and `$0.1`?  If you change the signature to take `[Pet]` and return `[Pet]` you can get rid of the forced casting. `NSComparisonResult` can be inferred by Swift and left off.

Comment: @vacawama I just kept it as AnyObject to make it similar to the OP question. It is obvious that I can use [Pet]

Comment: Yeah. I figured that was the reason after I commented. It is probably a good idea to suggest to OP to use [Pet] because it will crash if anything else is passed.